# PySpark - RDD to DataFrame in ALS output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark's recommendation system.

After train a model, I did the code below to obtain the recommendation
    model.recommendProductsForUsers(2)

```py
[(10000, (Rating(user=10000, product=14780773, rating=7.35695469892999e-05), 
          Rating(user=10000, product=17229476, rating=5.648606256948921e-05))), 
 (0, (Rating(user=0, product=16750010, rating=0.04405213492474741), 
      Rating(user=0, product=17416511, rating=0.019491942665715176))), 
 (20000, (Rating(user=20000, product=17433348, rating=0.017938298063142653), 
          Rating(user=20000, product=17333969, rating=0.01505112418739887)))]
```

In this case `Rec` is an `RDD` see below.

```
>>> type(Rec)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
```

How Can I put this information in a data frame like

```
 User | Product   | Rating 
1000  |  14780773 | 7.3e-05
1000  |  17229675 | 5.6e-05
(...)     (...)     (...) 
2000  |  17333969 | 0.015
```

thanks for you time

Comment: The necessary function is [covered in the PySpark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html). Look up `createDataFrame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To verify, I used the following pyspark code to reproduce your `RDD`:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import Rating

Rec = sc.parallelize([(10000, (Rating(user=10000, product=14780773, rating=7.35695469892999e-05), 
                               Rating(user=10000, product=17229476, rating=5.648606256948921e-05))), 
                      (0, (Rating(user=0, product=16750010, rating=0.04405213492474741), 
                           Rating(user=0, product=17416511, rating=0.019491942665715176))), 
                      (20000, (Rating(user=20000, product=17433348, rating=0.017938298063142653), 
                               Rating(user=20000, product=17333969, rating=0.01505112418739887)))])
```

This RDD is composed of key-value pairs, each value consisting of a record with Rating tuples. You need to map the RDD to keep only the records, and then explode the result to have separate tuples for each recommendation. The `flatMap(f)` function will condense these two steps like so:

```py
flatRec = Rec.flatMap(lambda p: p[1])
```

which results in a RDD in the form:

```
[Rating(user=10000, product=14780773, rating=7.35695469892999e-05),
 Rating(user=10000, product=17229476, rating=5.648606256948921e-05),
 Rating(user=0, product=16750010, rating=0.04405213492474741),
 Rating(user=0, product=17416511, rating=0.019491942665715176),
 Rating(user=20000, product=17433348, rating=0.017938298063142653),
 Rating(user=20000, product=17333969, rating=0.01505112418739887)]
```

Now all it takes is to use the `createDataFrame` function to turn this into a DataFrame. Each Rating tuple will be turned into a DataFrame Row, and since the items are labeled, you don't need to specify a schema.

```py
recDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(flatRec).show()
```

This will output the following:

```
+-----+--------+--------------------+
| user| product|              rating|
+-----+--------+--------------------+
|10000|14780773| 7.35695469892999E-5|
|10000|17229476|5.648606256948921E-5|
|    0|16750010| 0.04405213492474741|
|    0|17416511|0.019491942665715176|
|20000|17433348|0.017938298063142653|
|20000|17333969| 0.01505112418739887|
+-----+--------+--------------------+
```